# Customize WorkFlow Message Dialog box in Experience editor

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

In Experience Editor Mode when we click on the work flow command,the below dialog box comes up, How can I show a customized dialog instead of default:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18010434/157833

Comment: That is similar, How can i add field in this. Suppose i want to add EmailId or a Subject text field.

Comment: Just replace the `Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Input("Enter a comment:", string.Empty); args.WaitForPostBack();` with whatever you want

Comment: It is not working for me, I am using Sitecore 9. I have created a custom class with the method comment and added the custom Field and in Shell/Application/WorkBox/Workbox.xml i have updated the code beside as my custom class. The changes are not getting reflected in Page.
Also I have a custom xml in shell/Application/Dialogs/Custom.xml, this file contains custom Fields and its code beside is a custom cs.When i click on a workflow from Gutter in Content Editor mode the above custom dialog box comes up. Why is it not coming for ExperienceEditor.the behaviour of Gutter and EE workflow isnt same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new custom template for comments.
[image]

Assign  this template to the respective  workflow command in the Comment  Template field

[image]

Now you can see your customized dialog

[image]